# mongo aggregation issue after spring boot version upgrade to 2.5.14 from 2.4.13

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mappingexception

The aggregation was working fine before the spring boot version upgrade. After upgrading to 2.5.14, I'm facing issue with MongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation aggregation, Class<?> inputType, Class outputType) as :

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot convert [] of type class java.util.ArrayList into an instance of class java.lang.String! Implement a custom Converter<class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.String> and register it with the CustomConversions.
```

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am facing same issue in 2.7.7

Comment: @mifol68042 I kept using the earlier version of spring-data-mongodb i.e <version>3.1.15</version>